# How to disable a wp filter in a certain admin panel page

Tags: filters

One of my filters is breaking a plugin that enables featured images for categories.
Here's its code:

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
if (!$caption) {
    $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );

    $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='photoswipe align$align'>";
    if ($url) { $html5 .= '<a href="'.$url.'">'; }
    $html5 .= '<img src="'.$src[0].'" class="image" width="'.$src[1].'" height="'.$src[2].'" ';
    if ($alt) { $html5 .= 'alt="'.$alt.'" '; }
    $html5 .= '/>';
    if ($url) { $html5 .= '</a>'; }
    $html5 .= "</figure>";
    return $html5;
} else {
    return $html;
}   
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Is there an easy way to disable this filter entirely when the user is on the category management page in the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I guess:

```
function my_init() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow != 'edit-tags.php' ) {
        add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

There is also [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function, which will be perfect here, but... You can use it after `admin_init` hook, and your `image_send_to_editor` is called earlier, I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem.

For more information, I'm using this PHP class for custom category images: 
https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly have you done? What is the problem now? Are you sure that this filter is added correctly and that it runs?

Comment: It's added correctly. The problem might be somewhere else, I guess. When I click the button to add a category image, the normal WP media modal window appears. I can select the image and it gets marked as selected as it should but the moment I save changes, it's gone. I think the problem might be with not-so-flexible functions in this PHP class as it works fine with the default WP image_send_to_editor.

Comment: I see where the problem is: the html5_insert_image filter somehow prevents the function in the PHP Tax Meta Class to get the ID of the selected image. Not sure how to fix it yet.